# is there a way to make python type in google without getting into anything?

Tags: python

so im trying to make a code that you copy what you want then you press the hotkey and i want python to open google and type there "what is the meaning of (what ever word you want) in Hebrew"
and then close python after the code is complete is there a way to do that?
this is the code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, KeyCode, Listener
import webbrowser
from googlesearch import search
import pyperclip
def function_1():
    """ One of your functions to be executed by a combination """
    query='what is the mening of '+pyperclip.paste()+'in hebrew'
    for res in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=10, pause=2):
        webbrowser.open(res)

combination_to_function = {
    frozenset([Key.delete, KeyCode(vk=67)]): function_1  # delete + c
    }
pressed_vks = set()


def get_vk(key):
    """
    Get the virtual key code from a key.
    These are used so case/shift modifications are ignored.
    """
    return key.vk if hasattr(key, 'vk') else key.value.vk


def is_combination_pressed(combination):
    """ Check if a combination is satisfied using the keys pressed in pressed_vks """
    return all([get_vk(key) in pressed_vks for key in combination])


def on_press(key):
    """ When a key is pressed """
    vk = get_vk(key)  # Get the key's vk
    pressed_vks.add(vk)  # Add it to the set of currently pressed keys

    for combination in combination_to_function:  # Loop through each combination
        if is_combination_pressed(combination):  # Check if all keys in the combination are pressed
            combination_to_function[combination]()  # If so, execute the function


def on_release(key):
    """ When a key is released """
    vk = get_vk(key)  # Get the key's vk
    pressed_vks.remove(vk)  # Remove it from the set of currently pressed keys


with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply need to open the browser and execute a search you can use this.

```py
import webbrowser

def search_google(subject):
    webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=What is the meaning of " 
                    + subject 
                    + " in Hebrew")
search_google("Sample")
```

Additional parameters can also be used, take a look at [this blogpost by Pete Watson-Wailes](https://moz.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-google-search-parameters)

Comment: can you help me place this in the code idk how to i already tried like i dont know what i need to change and what not and where sould i put this

Comment: You can use this search_google function whenever you wanna open a browser and search for the word. How you want to implement it specifically is up to you !

Comment: if i want to put it here where would i be able to do that ?                 def function_1():
    """ One of your functions to be executed by a combination """
    query='what is the mening of '+pyperclip.paste()+'in hebrew'
    for res in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=10, pause=2):
        webbrowser.open(res)